# ExtJS 4.2 add frame to menus with different style than panels

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4.2

I would like to add a frame to my menu so I could use border radius, but I do not want to derive the frame background color from the definition of my panels.

As I see it now the frame can only be defined on the panel level and the menu inherits this definition.

Can it be done?

Answer (score -1):

The way you handle these is to use custom theme. ext-4.2.1-gpl/ext-4.2.1.883/docs/index.html#!/guide/theming will be help . It is in the extjs (sencha) SDK.
more [link](http://existdissolve.com/2011/09/extjs-4-theming-custom-uis/)

Comment: This is not useful as I am already using a custom, but the menu css variables seam to derive from the panel variable.

Comment: I have ended up using the following ui to achive this [code]@include extjs-panel-ui(
    $ui-label: 'popupmenu-framed',
 $ui-border-color:#47607E,
    $ui-body-background-color:#47607E,
    $ui-body-border-width:0px,
    $ui-border-radius:5px
);[code]